# Find div inside div with text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have not paste all the `div` content here as it is too long

```
<div id="calendar_month">
    <div>
        <div></div>
        <div>DEMO</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried this

```
 $("#calendar_month").children().each(function () {
     if ($(this).text() == "DEMO") {
         $(this).text("");
     }
 });
```

Comment: so what is the problem? show us your html code, otherwise it is difficult for us to help you.

Comment: We don't know what is the problem with this code, what you expect and what is the HTML code concerned.

Comment: Remember that unless you format your question properly, html elements won't be showed in clear text!

Comment: where is element with id `calendar_month`???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
$( "#calendar_month div:contains('DEMO')" )
```

Or after you edit your OP:

```js
$( "#Calendar > div > div:contains('DEMO')" ).text("");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Calendar">
    <div>
        <div>test</div>
        <div>DEMO</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or after @BhushanKawadkar comment you can use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```js
$( "#Calendar > div > div" )
  .filter(function( index ) {
    return $(this).text() == "DEMO";
  }).text("");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Calendar">
    <div>
        <div>test</div>
        <div>DEMO</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `contains` will not give exact match and it will act like `indexOf` function. And as per OP, he is searching for exact match.

Answer (score 1):

Your `div` that contains  text DEMO is not a direct children of `div` with id `calendar_month`. In your HTML `children()` will return the first div only.

Use [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Try:

```
$("#calendar_month").find('div').each(function () {
     if ($(this).text() == "DEMO") {
         $(this).text("");
     }
 });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3b18bquk/)

Or another way(not recommended but just posting for the logic) to this particular markup is to use

```
$("#calendar_month").children().children().each(function () {
     if ($(this).text() == "DEMO") {
         $(this).text("");
     }
 });
```